# Ajax posting strings with numbers, but not with letters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have an ajax call to an external php file that is using a mysql query to look up users with a unique ID.  This function works beautifully if the ID is all numbers, but if the ID starts with a letter, then nothing even posts to the php file.

I have printed to the error log, and nothing is happening at all when the button is clicked and the ID starts with a letter.  I printed the data types of both a fully-numeric ID and an alphanumeric ID, and they are both strings with no hidden special characters in them.

I am completely lost and confused, can anybody offer some insight on how to get these values to post?  Here is my code for the ajax call:

```
var value = <?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>;
    $(function() {
        $( "#emailbutton" ).click(function() {
            $.post('emailaddresses.php',{value:value}, function(data){
                $("#email").html(data);
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: is `var value = 1a34` valid javascript?

Comment: You have simply left out the string delimiters around `"<?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>"`.. only numerics can work as literals without the quotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply left out the string delimiters around `"<?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>"`... only numerics can work as literals without the quotes :)

```
var value = "<?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>";
$(function() {
    $( "#emailbutton" ).click(function() {
        $.post('emailaddresses.php',{value:value}, function(data){
            $("#email").html(data);
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

for example, if the value returned was `123`, then you would generate the following JavaScript (which is valid):

```
var value = 123;
```

but when you returned a non-numeric ID it generated invalid JavaScript like:

```
var value = a123;  <=== Assigns undefined unless a variable called a123 also exists with a value
```

when you really needed:

```
var value = "a123";
```

Comment: @Stryner: Quite correct. Changed to suit the "pendantically challenged" :)

Comment: Oh my goodness.  It is almost painful how simple that answer was.  Thank you so so much, it worked like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Because javascript is encountering error due to `var value = a12313` is not a valid JS syntax for string. Correct one should be `var value = 'a12313'`. So you need to change `var value = <?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>;` to `var value = '<?php echo $userinfo['ID']; ?>';` to handle string ids